# server side rendering problem with vuejs cli 3

Tags: vue.js, server-side-rendering, vue-cli-3

I am working on a vuejs app , and I am trying to use server side rendering, but I am having a problem with the rendering, but I am having this error when I start my server.

> [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /main.js from localhost:8080 to http://localhost:8081 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)

I can see the content of server page localhost:8080, but the client page in localhost:8081 cannot be reached. 
I am using this code in [Github](https://github.com/eddyerburgh/vue-cli-ssr-example)  I am testing with this vue component:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'Blog',
  data () {
    return {
      blog: null,
      error: null
    }
  },
  beforeCreate: function() {
    axios({ method: "GET", "url": "path to api" }).then(result => {
        this.blog = result.data.blogs[0];
      },
      error => {
        this.error = error;
      });
  },
  mounted () {
    axios({ method: "GET", "url": "path to api" }).then(result => {
        this.blog = result.data.blogs[0];
      },
      error => {
        this.error = error;
      });
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <div class="Blog">
    <section>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="page-title">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">
                  <h2><span>{{ blog.title }}</span></h2>
                  <!-- Other data here! -->
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</template>
```

for the server page, I just can see some css but I cannot see the data that I get from axios! But I see that the blog property contains the data, it's just not displayed in the page. Any help would be very appreciated.